# C# HasValue in reference types

Tags: c#, reference, nullable, reference-type

Is it somehow possible to use `Nullable<>.HasValue` on reference types?

Assume we have this example from value types:

```
int? a = GetNullOrValue(); // completely randomly gets random number or null
if (a.HasValue) return 0;
```

What I want to accomplish is this:

```
class Foo 
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

Foo foo = GetNullOrFoo(); // completely randomly gets Foo ref. or null

if (foo.HasValue) return foo.Bar; // of course this will throw NullReferenceException if foo is null
```

I want to achieve this for better readability as I prefer "word stuff", not "symbol stuff" (`x.HasValue` instead of `x != null`).

Comment: It may seem to improve the readability for *you*, at this time, but it means you end up writing non-idiomatic C# that is then harder to understand for any one new to your code (e.g. us lot on SO if you have any issues and want to ask questions that includes such usage). You also have to learn the idiomatic form to be able to understand other's C# code.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this will improve readability _only for me_, but it's needed _only_ for private solution. Everywhere else (at work or with team) I adapt to specific syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write an extension method.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static bool HasValue<T>(this T self) where T : class
    {
        return self != null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
if (foo.HasValue()) return foo.Bar;
```

but, honestly `x != null` is simple, these kind of extension methods will be confusing for maintainers, I won't recommend it.

Also read further if you're going to use this approach. This will work only when there is no instance method named `HasValue`, if there is any instance method will be called, not the extension method. Hence it will result in `NullReferenceException`. Not to be surprised with the results. So think twice before you do this.

---

> Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a
> violent psychopath who knows where you live.

Quote from [Code For The Maintainer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeForTheMaintainer)

Comment: Thank you! As for maintaining the code - there won't be any more maintainers than me _anytime_. So that psychopath knows where he lives already - at my own house :) Thank you one more time!

Comment: I bet, you may feel it readable right now. but, in future you'll realize how silly you were.. :) and it makes the situation even worse when there is an instance method named `HasValue`. In that case your extension will not be called and results in `NullReferenceException`. So it may confuse you also.